# SQL query to find rows which does not contain the requested code type

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which contain ind_ref and code_type.
I want to find only those ind_ref which does not have the code_type=3299. Below is the example table.

```
IND_REF CODE TYPE
   84815    9573
   84815    9415
   84816    3299<----don't want this IND_REF
   84816    9415
   84817    3299<----don't want this IND_REF
   84817    9573
   84818    9577
   84818    9573
```

I want the output contain only IND_REF

```
Ind_ref
 84815
 84818
```

Any Help much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `group by` and `having`:

```
select ind_ref
from t
group by ind_ref
having sum(case when type = 3299 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This returns one row per `ind_ref`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks alot Brother Gordon. You solved my problem. I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the data by `ind_ref` and take only those having no code 3299

```
select ind_ref
from your_table
group by ind_ref
having sum(case when code_type = 3299 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks @juergen, your help much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select distinct t.IND_REF
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.IND_REF = t.IND_REF and t1.CODETYPE = 3299
                 );
```

Here is [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5cd0f274ffaa8a93d01ca89dadf961ae).

Comment: it didnt worked , still got those ind_ref which contains the code 3299. Gordon's query solved it.

Comment: @Biswa. . .  Query is work if you just modify it with appropriate column name. You can check fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

use `not in`

```
    with your_table (IND_REF, codetype) as (

   SELECT 84815  ,  9573UNION ALL
   SELECT 84815  ,  9415UNION ALL
   SELECT 84816  ,  3299UNION ALL
   SELECT 84816  ,  9415UNION ALL
   SELECT 84817  ,  3299UNION ALL
   SELECT 84817  ,  9573UNION ALL
   SELECT 84818  ,  9577UNION ALL
   SELECT 84818  ,  9573
)select distinct t.IND_REF from your_table t where t.IND_REF not in
    ( select IND_REF from your_table t1 where         
       t1.codetype=3299
    )

    output
    IND_REF
    84815
    84818
```

And not exists also works fine

```
with your_table (IND_REF, codetype) as (

   SELECT 84815  ,  9573UNION ALL
   SELECT 84815  ,  9415UNION ALL
   SELECT 84816  ,  3299UNION ALL
   SELECT 84816  ,  9415UNION ALL
   SELECT 84817  ,  3299UNION ALL
   SELECT 84817  ,  9573UNION ALL
   SELECT 84818  ,  9577UNION ALL
   SELECT 84818  ,  9573
)

select distinct t.IND_REF
from your_table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from your_table t1 
                  where t1.IND_REF = t.IND_REF and t1.codetype = 3299
                 );
```

[Demo in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9715292c10bf07bc9c865a6a23203e85)

Comment: it didnt worked , still got those ind_ref which contains the code 3299. Gordon's query solved it.

Comment: Hi Brother, i have checked and it doesnt gives me any result. :( Sorry about that.

Comment: @Biswa it works fine i checked and previous version also worked

Comment: @Biswa bro thanks but i cheked both version is worked fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9715292c10bf07bc9c865a6a23203e85